# Delphi 10.1 - Google Play Console - Review and Release Error "This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement."

Tags: android, delphi, google-play-console

I have developed and uploaded an Android application written in Delphi 10.1 to the Google Play Console.

On the Google Play Console, I'm at the stage called "Review and release" (Production|Releases|Edit application(button)|Review Release button)

I have 1 error message that looks like its denying me to "Start rollout to Production".

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: [2]
>
> Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to update Delphi to 10.3.3 or later.  Check this:

[Delphi Android 64-bit Support in RAD Studio 10.3.3](https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2019-delphi-android-64bit-rad-1033.html)

Comment: This is also documented on Embarcadero's DocWiki: [Submitting Your Android App to Google Play: Android App Bundle Support](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Submitting_Your_Android_App_to_Google_Play)